# Converting OpenCV histogram to curve and vise versa

Tags: python, opencv, filter, histogram, curve

Using OpenCV in python, I got the histogram of one channel in an image, Can I convert it to a curve so as to multiply this new curve with another curve then return the output curve to a histogram to act as a filter on my image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would first have to extract the histogram as a function of the range [0, 255], in the form of an array. Then using the scipy library or the lmfit library (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html), you can fit the curve and extract a function.

The function would of the form

```
y = f(x)
```

where `x` is the range [0,255].

Next you would have to convert the other function into a similar function

```
z = g(x)
```

using the tutorial above.

Its important to keep in mind, that you shouldnt blindly fit a random function to the data. You need to know the general nature of the data and whether `f(x)` or `g(x)` is a relatively good fit or not. You may have to do some trial and error here.

Once you have obtained both `f(x)` and `g(x)` you can then create a third vector `m` with whatever range you have in mind and use `f(m)*g(m)` to multiply.